# Почему при hover Цвет фона не меняется?

Tags: css

```css
.gallery {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1366px;
}

.container {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}

.container img {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.container span {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 140px;
  top: 125px;
  color: white;
}

.container:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.container img:hover {
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="img" src="" width="337" height="300">
    <span class="pe-7s-look pe-3x dropdown"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/337x300" width="337" height="300">
    <span class="pe-7s-look pe-3x dropdown"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/337x300" width="337" height="300">
    <span class="pe-7s-look pe-3x dropdown"> </span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/337x300" width="337" height="300">
    <span class="pe-7s-look pe-3x dropdown"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/337x300" width="337" height="300">
    <span class="pe-7s-look pe-3x dropdown"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/337x300" width="337" height="300">
    <span class="pe-7s-look pe-3x dropdown"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/337x300" width="337" height="300">
    <span class="pe-7s-look pe-3x dropdown"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/337x300" width="337" height="300">
    <span class="pe-7s-look pe-3x dropdown"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="load-more">Load more works</div>
</div>
```

Почему при hover на изображение Цвет фона не меняется?

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что не меняется?

Comment: визуальных эффектов не наблюдаю

Comment: Картинка же непрозрачная. как ты хочешь увидеть фон под ней?

Comment: Убедиться, что все работает, ты можешь на первой картинке, где ты не указал src

Comment: как тогда затменить изображение при наведении?

Comment: что сделать? _затменить_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Картинку при наведении можно делать прозрачной при помощи `opacity` а фон задавать родительскому блоку.

```css
.container{
  background-color:#000;
  display:inline-block;
}
img{
  max-width:100%;
  vertical-align:top;
  transition:all .3s ease;
}
img:hover{
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/337x300" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

у img не может быть фона, его нужно задавать блокам в котором находится картинка